# Sum of gamma and normal random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

If $X$ has an exponential distribution and $Y$ is normally distributed random variable, then what is the distribution of $Z=X+Y$?

Comment: It is the inverse Fourier transform of the product between the CF of $X$ and the CF of $Y$. Do we know something more about the mean values of the two distributions?

Comment: In any case, we can compute the pdf of $X+Y$ in terms of the error function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function): just complete the square when solving the convolution integral.

Comment: The exponential has $1/\lambda$ as a mean while $\mu$ is the mean of the normal distribution.

Comment: The title says "gamma" but the body of the question uses an exponential distribution.  The question also says nothing about independence of $X$ and $Y$, and so it is not possible to obtain the distribution of $X+Y$ without knowing the joint distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convolution between the pdfs of $X$ and $Y$, given by:
$$ f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{x\geq 0},\qquad f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$
leads to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f_{X+Y}(x) &=& \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\lambda t-\frac{(x-t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dt\\&=&\frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\lambda}{2}(2\mu+\lambda\sigma^2-2x)\right)\cdot\left(-1+\frac{1}{\sigma}+\text{Erfc}\left(\frac{\mu+\lambda \sigma^2-x}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $\text{Erfc}$ is the [complementary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). It is a unimodal distribution quite close to the normal distribution with mean $\mu+\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and variance $\sigma^2+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, but with a non-zero skewness.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: For this to be correct one needs to assume independence of $X$ and $Y$, which is never stated.

Comment: Of course, I should have mentioned such assumption.